# Why does my UIButton remain after a segue?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I've been experimenting and practicing building apps programmatically and just can't understand why my UIButton from the root VC remains in the next view after a modal segue. When I did it through the storyboard, all of the elements in the view would disappear.

My rootVC is made of one layer and a UIButton over it:

[image]

pressing the button modally presents the next view controller, but the UIButton remains:

[image]

There are no references to the UIButton in the second VC file. Here's the code from the rootVC:

```
var imInChinaButton : UIButton {
        var button = UIButton( frame: CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 300,
            height: 300))
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "button"), for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("hello", for: .normal)
        button.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        button.center = view.center
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }

    self.view.addSubview(imInChinaButton)
}

@objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pressedButton"), for: .normal)
    let resultsViewController = ResultsViewController()
    self.navigationController!.present(resultsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any help would be awesome! Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change background of modal ,  in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .red
```

//

If you no longer need the backVC , you can

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController =  ResultsViewController()
```

but hiding temporarily is not possible you can do this to hide them before present  but it's not a good practise

```
self.view.subviews.forEach { $0.isHidden = true }
```

the best thing is to change the backgroundColor or completely clear the old rootVC

Comment: so the second VC? Is there a best practice way to go about doing that?

Comment: yes in the secondVC , the VC's background color was transparent

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, a modal segue simply stacks all the views from the next VC on top of the current on? Is there a way to temporarily "clear" the rootVC then? Only because I want the background to be the same, and I don't know whether there will be any performance problems that would come from having multiple push/modal segues on top of each other...

Comment: Churr bro! You're a legend